# Adding layer to canvas crashes QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, mapcanvas

I am having some difficulties in adding a layer to my canvas or even to main project. I create a plugin in QGIS 3.10. This plugin has a table of contents and a canvas to open some maps. I search and find this code:

```py
 # display file in canvas
fileCI = diretory to my shapefile
file_info_norm = QFileInfo(str(fileCI))

# vector layer
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(fileCI, file_info_norm.fileName(), 'ogr')

if not vlayer.isValid():
    return

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
self.canvas.setExtent(vlayer.extent())
```

However my QGIS always crashes when I run my code. I cannot see why this happens.

I create a widget in Qt Designer and promote to QgsMapCanvas.

Then in dialog in `init` function I create these lines of code:

```py
self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
self.canvas.setCanvasColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
self.canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
self.canvas.enableAntiAliasing(True)
self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
```

And then I define the lines above. The shapefile is added to the QGIS canvas but not to my `QWidget` promoted to `QgsMapCanvas`. The shapefile is a point shapefile in [EPSG: 3763 coordinate system](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3763/).

My dialog code is:

```
import os

from qgis.PyQt import uic
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


# This loads your .ui file so that PyQt can populate your plugin with the elements from Qt Designer
FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'coal_mine_dialog_base.ui'))


class PluginDialog(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(PluginDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer through FORM_CLASS.
        # After self.setupUi() you can access any designer object by doing
        # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
        # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
        # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect

        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.layers = []
        self.canvas.setCanvasColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
        self.canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
        self.canvas.enableAntiAliasing(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
        self.initialize_map()




        self.actionZoomIn = QAction("Zoom in", self)
        self.actionZoomOut = QAction("Zoom out", self)
        self.actionPan = QAction("Pan", self)

        self.actionZoomIn.setCheckable(True)
        self.actionZoomOut.setCheckable(True)
        self.actionPan.setCheckable(True)

        self.actionZoomIn.triggered.connect(self.zoomIn)
        self.actionZoomOut.triggered.connect(self.zoomOut)
        self.actionPan.triggered.connect(self.pan)

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar("Canvas actions")
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.actionZoomIn)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.actionZoomOut)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.actionPan)

        # create the map tools
        self.toolPan = QgsMapToolPan(self.canvas)
        self.toolPan.setAction(self.actionPan)
        self.toolZoomIn = QgsMapToolZoom(self.canvas, False)  # false = in
        self.toolZoomIn.setAction(self.actionZoomIn)
        self.toolZoomOut = QgsMapToolZoom(self.canvas, True)  # true = out
        self.toolZoomOut.setAction(self.actionZoomOut)

        self.pan()



        self.root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
        self.bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(self.root, self.canvas)
        self.model = QgsLayerTreeModel(self.root)
        self.model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeReorder)
        self.model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeRename)
        self.model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeChangeVisibility)
        self.model.testFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.ShowLegend)
        self.model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.ShowLegendAsTree)
        self.view = QgsLayerTreeView()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        # QMessageBox.about(self,'teste',str(self.view))

        self.createLegendWidget()  # Create the legend widget
        provider = MyMenuProvider(self.view, self.canvas)
        # QMessageBox.about(self,'teste',str(self.view.currentLayer()))
        self.view.setMenuProvider(provider)

        self.setupUi(self)
```

I only adapt the code to the original code created by QtDesigner.

Comment: Instead of `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)`, try this one `self.canvas.setLayers([vlayer])`

Comment: I also try with that line. It crashes again. This little piece of code in the main script of the plugin. However I change to the dialog script and part of it works. However, it only opens in QGIS canvas and not in my personal canvas, even if I put two more lines such as:  self.canvas.setExtent(vlayer.extent())
        self.canvas.setLayers([vlayer])

Comment: I think we need to see how you code your class for see how `self.canvas` is constructed and an extract / description of your layer (geometry type, coordinate system, etc.).

Comment: I create a widget in Qt Designer and promote to QgsMapCanvas. Then in dialog in __init__ function I create these lines of code: self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.canvas.setCanvasColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
        self.canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
        self.canvas.enableAntiAliasing(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
And then I define the lines that I put in my original answer. The shapefile is added to the QGIS canvas but not to my QWidget promoted to QgsMapCanvas. The shapefile is a point shapefile in EPSG3763 coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, I think is that you lost the reference to the `QgsVectorLayer` outside the function, the solution is to define `self.layers`, see below :

```py
class My_dlg(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(My_dlg, self).__init__(parent)
        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.layers = []
        self.canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
        self.canvas.enableAntiAliasing(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
        self.initialize_map()
        self.mt_pan = QgsMapToolPan(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.setMapTool(self.mt_pan)
        print(self.canvas.layerCount())

    def initialize_map(self):
        # display file in canvas
        shpdir = "/"
        fileCI = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open shp", shpdir, "Shapefiles (*.shp)")[0]
        file_info_norm = QFileInfo(str(fileCI))

        # vector layer
        vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(fileCI, "my_layer", "ogr")
        self.layers.append(vlayer)

        if vlayer.isValid():
            self.canvas.setLayers(self.layers)
            self.canvas.waitWhileRendering()
            self.canvas.setExtent(vlayer.extent())
            self.canvas.refresh()
        else:
            print("Layer not valid")


mw = My_dlg()
mw.show()
```

Comment: I try exactly as you told me but in this case QGIS crashes again.

Comment: When I copy this code into my QGIS Python editor and run it, it works perfectly (QGIS 3.10 Ubuntu).

Comment: Did you create the QgsMapCanvas in QtDesigner as I did?

Comment: No, look at the code, it's created at the line 4.

Comment: I think that my problem is in that step. I create a QWidget in QtDesigner and I initialize the variable self.canvas also in the dialog class. But I try to remove the QWidget from QtDesigner and the canvas disappear. I think that this is my problem.

Comment: Can you provide in your question the beginning of your code, the place where you load your `.ui` file, to look if you correctly call `setupUI`, etc. ?

Comment: I edit my question with some more code. Some functions are not presented in the code. But are just functions called in the main __init__ function.

Comment: Try with placing the `setupUI` just after the line with `super(...`, and comment / delete the line with `self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()` if in Qt Designer, the `QgsMapCanvas` object name is `canvas`.

Comment: I got it. In fact it was my mistake. Because the name of the object in QtDesigner was widget and not canvas. That's why the connection was not correctly performed. Now I got it! I replace all the canvas by widget, remove the definition of QgsMapCanvas and place the setupUI after the super(). It works!